# ng-repeat duplicate itens in the loop when $compiled is used

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to load some contents into a bootstrap's popover. This content is the the html elements of a hidden div, which have, among other things, a ng-repeat that iterate under a list of objects. Ok, it works. But the ng-click don't work inside of popover. To solve, according what i read here in stackoverflow, i used the $compile option when i set the content to popover. Yes, it works also. However, when i do that, the list of objects is showed duplicate inside of it. Can someone show me what is wrong please?

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3eQmvtgaNMZcuSXqUrLo?p=preview)

```js
angular.module("app", [])
    .controller("progressBarCtrl", function($scope, $timeout, $compile) {
        $scope.value = 90;
  
  $scope.cursos = [
   { "nome": "Medicina", "percentual": "20" },
   { "nome": "Ciência da computação", "percentual": "90" }
   
  ];  
 
  $scope.showPopover = function() {
   $("#main").popover("show");   
  }
  
   $timeout(function() { 
   $scope.$apply(function() {  
   $("#main").popover({
    container: 'body',
    html: true,
    content: function () {
     return $compile($("#popper-content").html())($scope);       
    }
   }); 
   });
  });
  
  $scope.showAlert = function() {
   alert();
  };
  
    });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="progressBarCtrl">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-3" id="main" data-ng-mouseenter="showPopover()" data-placement="bottom" title="Progresso detalhado">
    <h4>Progresso geral:</h4>
        <div class="progress">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="{{value}}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: {{value}}%">
          {{value}}%
          </div>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="popper-content" class="hide"  >
    <div data-ng-repeat="curso in cursos">
     <h3>{{curso.nome}}:</h3>
        <div class="progress">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="{{curso.percentual}}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: {{curso.percentual}}%">
          {{curso.percentual}}%
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div ng-click="showAlert()">click-me</div>       
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this is surprisingly complex. Behind the scenes, your repeat is being executed twice. Once when the application loads, because it is sitting right there in a DIV inside the element (body) where you have applied the Angular controller.

To make this work right, you need to "hide" the template content not only with CSS, but rather hide it from Angular. You do this by either putting the template and external file (by far the most common thing, and real applications), or by using the script tag.

Also, in your example code you have called scope apply inside of $timeout; this is not necessary, $timeout calls it for you.

See the following plunker, I think it now does what you are looking for.

http://plnkr.co/edit/jKtG1W1V9a6MZI5uVPdP?p=preview

The most important bit of code:

```
    $timeout(function() {   
        $("#main").popover({
            container: 'body',
            html: true,
            content: function () {
                return $compile($templateCache.get('popper-content'))($scope);                          
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks @Kyle Cords. You save my life.